# Passing pointer to function that accepts reference in c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I guess this is a n00b question because I couldn't find anything about it on web...

Here is Point class:

```
class Point {
public:
   Point();
   Point(double x, double y);


   double getX() const;
   double getY() const;
   void setX(double);
   void setY(double);

   friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Point& obj);
private:
   double x;
   double y;
};
```

And here is an implementation of operator<< function:

```
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Point& obj) {
   os << "(" << obj.getX() << "," << obj.getY() << ")";
   return os;
}
```

Now, in main function I have `Point *p;`... How can I print it using `std::cout`?

Comment: dereference it with `*p`

Comment: `cout << *p << endl`

Comment: As long as p is not nullptr, need to check for that first

Comment: Definitely a n00b question, but you shouldn't get penalized for it.

Comment: well, I didn't mention that, but I have some experience with pointers so I tried this before and I got:

`undefined reference to 'operator<<(std::ostream&, Point const&)'`

Comment: By the way you don't need to make the streaming operator a friend, as it is implemented using only public getters.

Comment: Yeah, I know but NetBeans generated it for me with friend keyword so I left it...

So, is there anything that can help me to solve this problem? I mean, I passed two courses where we were using C so I know how pointers work and this problem really confuses me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I finally found out where was the problem.

Although all tutorials, books and even c++ reference agree that `inline` directive can be ignored by the compiler, it turns out that when I remove `inline` keyword from implementation of an overloaded function everything works.

Answer (score 3):

You need to dereference your pointer but as pointers can be null, you should check first.

```
if( p != nullptr )
   std::cout << *p << std::endl;
```

or even just

```
if( p )
   std::cout << *p << std::endl;
```

And now, go and read this in our community wiki, hopefully it will provide you the answers.

[What are the differences between a pointer variable and a reference variable in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in)

Comment: actually that link isn't in the community wiki but maybe it should be

Comment: Do you mean to have `-` before `nullptr`?

Comment: this works for me too, but I'm still getting undefined reference to `operator<<` function (using your code from main function) with my code

Comment: undefined reference is usually a linker error but you inlined it. Where in the code are all your files?